# Nothing as delimiter like sep=None or how to remove comma?

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter

I am doing the cartesian product from 2 csv files with each 1 column. The outcome should be a new csv with with 1 column in which are all the products.
Since the default delimiter is comma and `sep=None` or similar isn't allowed, how is it possible to have the product in one column without any comma?
First I thought the imported file `00` would have the delimiter but with `replace` and `delim_whitespace=False` I guess I made sure it doesn't comes from there (its anyways just one column).
I also tried to merge or join column 1 and column 2 of the final file with the cartesian product but coulnd't figure out how. Further I tried it with `replace(",", "")` but it didn't change the outcome.

**This is the code:**

```
import pandas as pd

vornamen = pd.read_csv(...\00.csv",header=None, encoding= 'unicode_escape')
nachnamen = pd.read_csv(...\01.csv",header=None, encoding= 'unicode_escape')

vornamen['_tmp'] = 1
nachnamen['_tmp'] = 1

df = pd.merge(vornamen,nachnamen,on='_tmp').drop('_tmp',axis=1)
df.to_csv(...\03.csv",header=None,index=False, sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `df.to_csv` method creates a CSV file, it creates the same amount of columns in the output file as are in the dataframe. Since you have 2 columns in the df dataframe, pandas will try to save 2 columns:

```py
...

>>> df = pd.merge(vornamen,nachnamen,on='_tmp').drop('mp',axis=1)
>>> df
   0_x      0_y
0  Jan     Hart
1  Jan  Johnson
2  Bob     Hart
3  Bob  Johnson
```

In order to have a single column, you can combine these 2 columns into a pandas Series object like this:

```py
>>> names = (df['0_x'] + ' ' + df['0_y'])
>>> names
0       Jan Hart
1    Jan Johnson
2       Bob Hart
3    Bob Johnson
dtype: object

>>> names.to_csv('names.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

If you then inspect the `names.csv` file, you can see that it contains the product of all the names in the 2 files:

```sh
➜  ~ cat names.csv
Jan Hart
Jan Johnson
Bob Hart
Bob Johnson
```

Comment: It works wonderfully! Exactly what I searched for. Many thanks Bob!!
I had tried it with df[0] + df[1] but it obviously didn't accept the form. So thanks again